# Chrome Allow or snooze all Notifications

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I plan to implement a `do not disturb` mode in Chrome as an extension/Chrome app but I don't know if Chrome offers any API to toggle notifications or somehow manage extensions e.g. in the following screenshot
[image]

So basically, I'm hoping Chrome provides a global method to snooze notifications or somehow offers some APIs with which exceptions can be managed and I could simply one by one `Block` all sites when `do not disturb` is desired and toggle back on when it needs to be turned off. Any leads?

Comment: Try adding a blocking rule for `*` via chrome.contentSettings API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [`chrome.contentSettings`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSettings#type-NotificationsContentSetting),

```
chrome.contentSettings.notifications.set({
    primaryPattern: '<all_urls>',
    setting: 'block'
});
```

Comment: I'm assuming this will explicitly allow or block all urls irrespective of what the user has allowed or blocked. Do I have a way of finding out the exceptions(hostnames/patterns user has set to 'allow' or 'ask' or 'block') as shown in the above picture? In that case I'll preserve user values and once the user wants to go back to their previous settings I'll have them

Comment: @user3677331, sorry but I didn't find a way to do that, maybe another question or seeking help on https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!forum/chromium-extensions?